# Python: calling overriden base class method in base class init

Tags: python, initialization, super

Consider the following classes, running python2.7:

```
class S(object):
  def __init__(self):
    print 'Si'
    self.reset()

  def reset(self):
    print 'Sr'
    self.a=0

class U1(S):
  def reset(self):
    print 'U1r'
    self.b=0
    super(S,self).reset()
```

The desired functionality is that

1. creating an instance of the base class calls its reset method;
2. creating an instance of the derived class calls its reset method, and also invokes the base class's reset method.

I get (1):

```
>>> print S().a
Si
Sr
0
```

but not (2):

```
>>> print U1().b
Si
U1r
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "tt.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.reset()
  File "tt.py", line 14, in reset
    super(S,self).reset()
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'reset'
```

What's the cleanest way to get what  I want?  I presume the error has something to do with the order in which class membership is getting constructed, but I can't figure it out from the documentation. . .

Answer (score 2):

You should be calling `super(U1, self).reset()` in `U1.reset()`. When you use `super`, you should always pass the name of the *current class* as the first argument, not the name of the parent class. [As stated in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super):

> **`super(type[, object-or-type])`**
>
> Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of *`type`*

`super` will look up the method on the parent or sibling of the `type` you provide. When you provide the parent class, it will try to find implementations of `reset` on parents/siblings of the parent, which will fail.

Comment: D'oh.  Thanks.  I had somehow been looking at too many examples, and gotten the idea that the purpose of the extra argument was to distinguish which superclass I wanted, if there were several.  And indeed, as the answers to the duplicate identified above make clear, you can do that, by looking at the __mro__ and naming the class before the one you want (which is why 'parent' isn't really right ...)

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

`super(U1, self).reset()`

In my head, I read "super(U1,..." as "parent of U1" to keep it straight.

Comment: Except in the simple case, 'parent' is misleading, as the answers to the duplicate pointer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000419/i-cant-get-super-to-work-in-python-2-7 explain, or see my comment above

Comment: Ah, thanks I would have never know that.